# Filtering existing objects with SQL query

Tags: sql, json, node.js, filter, filtering

I'm looking for a library that could filter javascript collections of objets from a SQL query. No such results on Google :/

For example, this objects collection...

```
var objects = [{id : 1, name : "o1"},{id : 2, name : "o2"}]
```

filtered with...

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE id = 1
```

would return...

```
[{id : 1, name : "o1"}]
```

Do you know if such a library already exists ? Or should I devellop it by myself... ? (Uhh --')

Thanks all !

Comment: Backbone.js http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where

Comment: You can NOT filter JS objects with SQL! To different Language and not to mention SQL is server side and JS client-side. Bottom line filtering JS with SQL not possible! Filtering JS objects with JS libs like backbone.js is possible

Comment: Sure this is two different languages ! But SQL can be client-side (Web SQL) and JS can be server side (NodeJS) ! Here's not the problem ;) Thanks for your answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all these answers ;)
Well, such a library does not seems to exist :/
I bypassed the problem and focused only on the Where clause : I built a class specialized in handling a where clause. This class can even return a SQL Where clause string (used in a further request) or filter a collection or objects.

Thanks for your answers, they all helped me in solving my problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)'s [where](http://underscorejs.org/#where) function. for example

```
var listOfPlays = [
 {title: "Cymbeline", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611},
 {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611},
 {title: "Sonnets", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1609},
]

>_.where(listOfPlays, {author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611});


=> [{title: "Cymbeline", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611},
    {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611}]
```

Comment: I already use it, and I knew this solution ;) But the SQL query needs to be parsed before beeing used in underscore/backbone. Thanks ;)

Comment: Did you use the Sequelize. Maybe there are what you want query solution on sequelize's "where" parameter when do findAll().

Comment: The project doesn't use Sequelize for the moment. But I took a look at it and built something working on where clause ;) Thanks ;)